# AWS IoT receive message

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, iot, aws-iot

Hello I try receive message from AWS IoT. For publishing I use php-sdk

```
use Aws\IotDataPlane\IotDataPlaneClient

$connectionParams = [
            'version' => 'latest',
            'region'  => $region,
            'credentials' => [
                'key' => $key,
                'secret' => $secret,
            ]
];

$this->client = new IotDataPlaneClient($connectionParams);
$this->client->publish([
                "payload" => $message,
                'qos' => 1,
                'topic' => $topic,
            ]);
```

But I it is no any method for receiving. Anyone knows how connect and receive messages?

Answer (score 0):

You need to subscribe to the MQTT topic. You have a few options.

1. You can connect the broker with Lambda, to Kinesis, SNS etc. So your receive handler can exist in lambda.
2. You can write code to subscribe to the MQTT broker yourself and put it in EC2, ECS etc with proper IAM roles/policies. The IoT endpoint in fact is a MQTT broker so thats the only config you will need to receive messages. The endpoint is visible on AWS IoT > Settings > Custom Endpoint

Lambda to receive messages will look something like this where event is an inbound MQTT message

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');

exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
    const id = event.id;
    const chan0 = event.chan0;
}
```